# Start multiple ObjectAnimator animations on the same object one after another

Tags: android, animation, objectanimator

I have a view in my app which I would like to animate while moving a finger on a surface view.
I don't want the view just to follow my finger but I would like to move it from its position to the new one with an animation.

For obtaining that result I intercept the movement of the finger on the surface view and start a new ObjectAnimator on the view to be animated, saying it to move to its new position. The problem is that, having all these ObjectAnimators which start on the same object in a so short time, the result is that I see the animation only when I stop to move the finger (seeing it moving to its final position).

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Does it work if you only start a single Animator?

Comment: In this case I think the most obvious solution is to cancel the previous animation when you start the new one

Comment: I already do it, but nothing...